# How to convert #defined string literal to a wide string literal?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert concatenated strings to wide-char with the C preprocessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192416/how-to-convert-concatenated-strings-to-wide-char-with-the-c-preprocessor)

I have a string literal defined using a #define:

```
#define B "1234\0"
```

How do I use this definition to get this wide string literal at compile time?:

```
L"1234\0"
```

(just the `#define`d string literal with `L` prepended to make it into a wide string).

I tried this:

```
#define MAKEWIDE(s) L##s
```

but this generates `LB`.

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192416/how-to-convert-concatenated-strings-to-wide-char-with-the-c-preprocessor

Comment: Also note that you don't generally need to put the `'\0'` character at the end of your literal strings - the compiler will do that for you. The only times I can think of when you need to do it yourself is if you actually need two null characters at the end of your string, or you need to ensure that a character array being initialized with the literal gets the null terminating character - in C, a char array of just the right size won't get the null character. Adding it yourself expliitly will encourage the compiler to generate at least a warning.  Both of these uses would be only rarely useful.

Comment: I expected someone would mention that \0. I am not responsible for the string literal and am not clear why it's there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Token pasting needs an additional level of indirection to deal properly with macros used as operands.  Try something like:

```
#define PASTE(x, y) x##y
#define MAKEWIDE(x) PASTE(L,x)
```

Comment: What's overly complicated - using a macro for this, or having to indirect the token paste through a helper macro?  The helper macro for token pasting is generally necessary to get expected results.  So, in general, there should be such a helper macro lying around already if token pasting is used anywhere else in the project.

Comment: I mean, according to standard C anyway, simple string concatenation should handle it without any preprocessor tricks.

Answer (score 7):

This will work just fine:

```
#define B "1234\0"
#define LB L"" B
```

Comment: Clever. I'll have to do some digging around though - I recall seeing this described elsewhere (and I had forgotten), but my recollection is that some compilers weren't able to deal with it.

Comment: OK - it's MSVC that can't do it: error C2308: concatenating mismatched strings Concatenating wide "" with narrow "1234"

Comment: The standard changed in this area from C90 to C99 - in C90 it's called out as undefined behavior; C99 changed this so that the literal is 'converts' to be a wide char string literal.  Since MS has never supported C99, the behavior is somewhat understandable...

Comment: Ah, I thought the behavior dated back to the beginning of wide character strings..

Comment: Just a message from 2016... VS2015 behaves correctly. Now we're 17 years after 99 I would suggest this is the best answer unless you're dealing with a really arcane platform.