# how to define macro to convert concatenated char string to wchar_t string in C

Tags: c, string, macros, wchar

Like `_T()` macro in Visual Studio, I defined and used my own `_L` macro as：

```
#define _L(x)  __L(x)
#define __L(x) L ## x
```

It works for:

```
wprintf(_L("abc\n"));
```

But gets a compilation error for:

```
wprintf(_L("abc\n""def\n"));
```

It reports *“string literals with Iifferent character kinds cannot be concatenated”.*
I also did:

```
#define _L2(x)  __L2(x)
#define __L2(x) L ## #x
wprintf(_L2("abc\n""def\n"));
```

The code gets compiled, but the `\n` doesn't work as an escape sequence of a new line. The `\n` becomes two characters, and the output of `wprintf` is:

> "abc\n""def\n"

How I can have a macro to convert two concatenated char string to `wchar_t`? The problem is I have some already existing macros：

```
#define BAR  "The fist line\n" \
             "The second line\n"
```

I want to covert them to a `wchar` string during compilation. The compiler is ICC in windows.

**Edit**:
The `_L` macro works in gcc, the MSVC and ICC didn't works, it's a compiler bug.
Thanks @R.. to comment me.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you don't need to write macro. Just place the string next to each other and they will auto concat into one. At least that works for gcc.

Comment: This is purely a bug in MSVC. The C languages allows concatenating different-width strings, and the result is a wide string.

Comment: @nhahtdh I am not to concat two string. I want to convert contacted string to wchar.

Comment: @R.. you are correct. the gcc works fine. But my MSVC and Icc doesn't. Thanks.

Comment: Concatenating with `L""` is the standard, canonical way to convert to a wide string.

Comment: @R: where in the language standard do you see that compilers must handle it in one particular way? I didn't find it, thus I can't consider it a bug. But please, enlighten me :)

Comment: It looks like MSVC conforms to C89 but not C99.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192416/how-to-convert-concatenated-strings-to-wide-char-with-the-c-preprocessor

Comment: @Windowsprogrammer Thanks. that's good feature in c99, but seems now only gcc support it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this.

Macros just do simple text processing. They can add `L` in the beginning, but can't tell that `"abc\n" "def\n"` are two strings, which need adding `L` twice.

You can make progress if you pass the strings to the macro separated by commas, rather than concatenated:
`L("abc\n", "def\n")`

It's trivial to define `L` that accepts exactly two strings:
`#define L2(a,b) _L(a) _L(b)`
Generalizing it to have a single macro that gets any number of parameters and adds `L`s in the correct place is possible, but more complicated. You can find clever macros doing such things in [Jens Gustedt's P99 macros](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/index.html).

Comment: Yes, I can, if the C compiler supports C99 standard correctly, like GCC.  another question said this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192416/how-to-convert-concatenated-strings-to-wide-char-with-the-c-preprocessor

Comment: @RolandXu, The preprocessor can't do what he wants, i.e. generate `L"abc" L"def"`. The compiler can (though MSVC seems not to) treat `L"abc" "def"` as a wide string entirely.

Comment: @ugoren OK, understand. The preprocesser can't. the compiler can if supports c99