# How to use stdint types with _tprintf in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, unicode

Take the following example:

```
char* fileName = "C:\\windows\\system32\\kernel32.dll";
uint32_t fileSize = 1163264;
printf("The size of %s is %"PRIu32"\n", fileName, fileSize);
```

Everything is fine, now if we want transparent unicode support via `tchar.h` the code would look like this:

```
TCHAR* fileName = _T("C:\\windows\\system32\\kernel32.dll");
uint32_t fileSize = 1163264;
_tprintf(_T("The size of %s is %")_T(PRIu32)_T("\n"), fileName, fileSize);
```

This works if unicode is **not** defined. However, if unicode is defined the compiler aborts with the following error:

```
error C2308: concatenating mismatched strings
Concatenating wide "The size of %s is %l" with narrow "u"
```

Now looking at Microsoft's inttypes.h I see:

```
...
#define _PFX_32  "l"
...
#define PRIu32       _PFX_32 "u"
```

Which means that the `_T(PRIu32)` in the above example resolves to:

```
_T("l" "u")
```

... which cannot work of course and explains the correct compiler error.

Thus my question is how did Microsoft imagine that we use their inttypes.h defines with _tprintf ?

Comment: Neither `_T` nor `_tprintf` are standard C. `inttypes.h` **is** and does not support other string literals than `char []`. Use standard C or stick completely with prorietary stuff.

Comment: Letting `PRIu32` expand to multiple string literals is arguably a standard violation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According<sup>1</sup>  to the current C standard, only one of the character sequences (read as: a string) must be prefixed by a an encoding prefix, and the rest of them are treated to have the same prefix, and are concatenated into a single string.

The encoding prefix is determined by the _T macro. It will resolve to nothing, if UNICODE is not defined, otherwise it will prepend `L` to the argument.

The solution would be to use the _T macro on the first string, no macro on the rest, and they will use the same encoding:

```
_tprintf(_T("The size of %s is %") PRIu32 "\n", fileName, fileSize);
```

But the Visual Studio version you're using isn't C99 compliant, so this feature is missing. It seems this was fixed in Visual Studio 2015.

The same usage is demonstrated in the example<sup>2</sup>  in the standard.

---

<sup>1</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.4.5 String literals 5)
In translation phase 6, the multibyte character sequences specified by any sequence of
adjacent character and identically-prefixed string literal tokens are concatenated into a
single multibyte character sequence. If any of the tokens has an encoding prefix, the
resulting multibyte character sequence is treated as having the same prefix; otherwise, it
is treated as a character string literal. Whether differently-prefixed wide string literal
tokens can be concatenated and, if so, the treatment of the resulting multibyte character
sequence are implementation-defined.

<sup>2</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 7.8.1 Macros for format specifiers 7)
`wprintf(L"The largest integer value is %020" PRIxMAX "\n", i);`

Comment: Not working with Visual Studio 2013. Even a simple `wprintf(L"Hello " "World");` results in `error C2308: concatenating mismatched strings: Concatenating wide "Hello " with narrow "World"`

Comment: I'm not quite following why this should be expected to work in MSVC when the OP's original code does not.  It seems like it would produce exactly the same situation that MSVC is rejecting.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Right, it wouldn't. It seems VS is non-compliant.

Comment: @2501 Nevertheless, awesome information, learned something. Very much appreciated!

Comment: @2501, FWIW, I don't think MSVC is non-conforming in this particular regard (just unsatisfactorily implemented).  As I read it, implementations are only required to concatenate *identically-prefixed* character and string literals.  Only if they choose to also concatenate mixed sequences of prefixed and unprefixed literals does the part about being treated as having the same prefix come into play.  Still, good answer.

Comment: @gollum VS2015 should support this.

Comment: @JohnBollinger https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192416/how-to-convert-concatenated-strings-to-wide-char-with-the-c-preprocessor

Comment: @2501, I'm not sure what you're trying to say.  The accepted answer to the question you cite is for C99.  It references that standard's provision analogous to C2011 6.4.5/5 (on which you rely).  The C2011 version adds the "identically-prefixed" qualification, which does not appear in the C99 version, and that's the crux of the issue.

Comment: @JohnBollinger See the example, quoted from the standard, in my answer.

Comment: I can confirm that this was fixed in VS2015. My solution is now to include  my own replacement inttypes.h `#if _MSC_VER < 1900`. Since this is one of many issues caused by Microsoft's impotence following standards,  a direct answer to my question does not seem to be possible.

Comment: @gollum Well, they are called micro*soft* :-) Please consider accepting my answer.